# Running a module controller in yii

Tags: php, yii

I have just created a module named `myfirstmodule` using gii in yii and then just hit the *URl* in my browser like:

> localhost/yii_learn/index.php?r=myfirstmodule

`defaultcontroller` will run and display the output. Now I created a new controller and view in the same module and just run by:

> http://localhost/yii_learn/index.php?r=myfirstmodule/mycontroller/index

It's redirecting me to home page of project.

Below is the code:

mycontroller.php

```
class mycontroller {
    //put your code here
    public function actionIndex(){
    $this->render('myfirst');
}
```

And my view file code is

```
 <?php
    $this->breadcrumbs=array(
    $this->module->id,
   );
 ?>
  <h1><?php echo $this->uniqueId . '/' . $this->action->id; ?></h1>
 <p>
  This is the view content for action "<?php echo $this->action->id; ?>".
  The action belongs to the controller "<?php echo get_class($this); ?>"
  in the "<?php echo $this->module->id; ?>" module.
 </p>
 <p>
  You may customize this page by editing <tt><?php echo __FILE__; ?></tt>
 </p>
```

Main.php file code

```
    <?php

    // uncomment the following to define a path alias
    // Yii::setPathOfAlias('local','path/to/local-folder');

   // This is the main Web application configuration. Any writable
   // CWebApplication properties can be configured here.
  return array(
  'basePath'=>dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..',
  'name'=>'My Web Application',

 // preloading 'log' component
 'preload'=>array('log'),

 // autoloading model and component classes
 'import'=>array(
    'application.models.*',
    'application.components.*',
),

'modules'=>array('testmodule','CustomerOnBoarding',
        'myfirstmodule'=>array(),
//            'myfirstmodule'=>array(
//                'class'=>'\myfirstmodule\DefaultController',
 //            ),
 // uncomment the following to enable the Gii tool

                'gii'=>array(
        'class'=>'system.gii.GiiModule',
            'password'=>false,
        // If removed, Gii defaults to localhost only. Edit carefully to    taste.
        'ipFilters'=>array('127.0.0.1','::1'),
    ),

),

// application components
  'components'=>array(
   'user'=>array(
        // enable cookie-based authentication
        'allowAutoLogin'=>true,
    ),

     // uncomment the following to enable URLs in path-format

      //        'urlManager'=>array(
      //                    'caseSensitive' => true,
      //                   'urlSuffix' => '/',
      //                    'showScriptName' => false,
      //
      //            'urlFormat'=>'path',
                                 'rules'=>array('myfirstmodule'=>'myfirstmodule/mycontroller/index',
           //                     '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view','<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',


    // database settings are configured in database.php
    'db'=>require(dirname(__FILE__).'/database.php'),

    'errorHandler'=>array(
        // use 'site/error' action to display errors
        'errorAction'=>'site/error',
    ),

    'log'=>array(
        'class'=>'CLogRouter',
        'routes'=>array(
            array(
                'class'=>'CFileLogRoute',
                'levels'=>'error, warning',
            ),
            // uncomment the following to show log messages on web pages

           //               array(
          //                    'class'=>'CWebLogRoute',
          //                ),

        ),
    ),

),

// application-level parameters that can be accessed
// using Yii::app()->params['paramName']
'params'=>array(
    // this is used in contact page
    'adminEmail'=>'webmaster@example.com',
),
 );
```

Can anyone help me in this, that how can I run my controller and view .

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow. It's really difficult for us to debug your code if you don't show us the actual code. Can you please edit your question, and show us the relevant controller code for each of the controllers? that way we can actually see what the bug might be and help you fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The format of the url is  `http://localhost/yii_learn/index.php?r=controllername/functionname`. If you want to access a function through url, it should be prefixed with `action`. For example a function `actionSampleFunction()` in `testcontroller` can be accessed by `http://localhost/yii_learn/index.php?r=testcontroller/samplefunction`.

Comment: Hi ,i did the same  with actionIndex but its not working .Kindly go through the edited post .

Answer (score 0):

Have you try via access rules for this action
like. Simply add this to your controller and try.

```
public function accessRules()
{
    return array(
        array('allow',  // allow all users to perform 'index' and 'view' actions
            'actions'=>array('index'),
            'users'=>array('*'),
        ),
    );
}
```

if worked let me know.

Comment: NO its still not working ,i have added main.php file code in my post ,kindly go through it .there  might be some problem in this file.Any help will be highly appreciated ,Thanks you